# High GLMER dispersion parameters

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, glmm, diagnostic

I am running a glmer with a random effect for count data (`x`) and two categorical variables (`y` and `z`):

```
fullmodel <- glmer(x ~ y * z + (1 | Replicate), 
                   family = poisson(), data = Data)
```

However, when I look at the dispersion parameter:

```
 > dispersion_glmer(fullmodel)
[1] 2.338742
```

It is way higher than 1. Does this mean my model is over dispersed? How do I correct it. I want to keep my random effect but when I tried to swap the family to quasipoisson it says you can't use it in `glmer()`.

---

Thank you ! I've run a negative binomial

```
model<-glmer.nb(z~y*z + (1|Replicate), family = negative.binomial, data = Data)
```

However I go some  Warning messages:

```
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0289023 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.269945 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
3: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.370829 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
```

Are these warnings of any concern? My dispersion parameter is now 1.02157 (between the 0.5 and 1.5 I was told it should be between)

Comment: Have you tried the negative binomial model?

Comment: Would the new model code just be:   model<-glmer.nb(x~y*z + (1|Replicate), data = Data)     ?

Comment: You can give a try in the `mixed_model()` function from the **GLMMadaptive** package as described in my answer above.

Answer (score 4):

To better check for over-dispersion you can use the simulated residuals provided by the [**DHARMa**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=DHARMa) package.

If you want to account for over-dispersion, you can use a negative binomial mixed effects model. This is provided by `glmer.nb()` in the **lme4** package and also by `mixed_model()` of the [**GLMMadaptive**](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/) package. The `glmer.nb()` fits the model using the Laplace approximation, whereas `mixed_model()` uses the more accurate adaptive Gaussian quadrature. For examples of the latter and checking also the fit of the model, check the vignette [Goodness-of-Fit for MixMod Objects](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Goodness_of_Fit.html).